# sqlalchemy fill a part of query with variable

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to edit **`users.query.all()`** to have something like **`db_table.query.all()`**. How I should edit this part?

```
def test(db_table):
    all = db_table.query.all()
    print (all)
    return 'ok'
```

I run the file this way:

```
python my-script.py [users]
```

And in the file the function will be called this way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(test(sys.argv[0]), debug=True)
```

By running above code, I will face with this error:

> ```
> all = db_table.query.all() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query'
> ```

I want to pass the table name into test function as a parameter and then put it in the query.

Comment: Er, just like that?

Comment: something like that, yeah. I want to pass the table name into test function as a parameter and then put it in the query.

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: @MrLeeh I've updated my question by the output error.

Comment: @niloofar As the error message says: You're passing a string as a function argument. This should be some kind of `Model` object instead. How do you call `test()`?

Comment: @MrLeeh I've updated the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing an argument to the script, you will just get a value in your example it is a string value. But you need an object. You can define a function and check the string value if it is same with your model name then return that object:

```
class User(db.Model):
    ...

def get_model(arg):
    if arg == 'users':
        return User
    return False

def test(db_table):
    db_table = get_model(db_table)
    if db_table:
        all = db_table.query.all()
        print (all)
        return 'ok'
```

Comment: Faced with `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`  which is pointing to `python my-script.py [users]`.

Comment: Try without `[]` `python my-script.py users` and `application.run(test(sys.argv[1]), debug=True)` `argv[0]` is name of your script

Comment: I did but again the same error pointing to `python my-script.py users`.

Comment: I think it's about the argument value can you share latest version of your whole code ?